# Django, unique time interval for the admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Greetings,
Assume I have such model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time models.DateTimeField()
```

For each Foo object that is having the same type, I need this time interval (end_time - start_time) to be unique so that creation of  a second Foo with a clashing interval won't be possible. How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation about [custom validation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) in the admin interface.

Basically you have to create your own (model) form, lets say `CustomFooAdminForm` and assign it to the admin model:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomFooAdminForm
```

and in the form you can have something like (see [custom validation in forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/validation/#ref-forms-validation)):

```
# more or less pseudo code
class CustomFooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CustomFooAdminForm, self).clean()
        interval = cleaned_data.get("end_time") - cleaned_data.get("start_time")
        type = cleaned_data.get("type")

        q = Foo.objects.extra(select={'interval':'time_end - time_start'}
        counter = q.filter(interval=intervak, type=type).count()

        if counter > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("ERROR!!!!")

        # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
        return cleaned_data
```

Maybe you have to transform the `DateTimeField`s to UNIX timestamps, before you can subtract them in SQL (`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (time_start)` for MySQL). Or you can use [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) in MySQL to get the difference. But note that you tie your application to a certain database if you use such special functions (as long as they are not available in other databases under the same name).

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed explanation! For the last part (tim difference), I guess timedelta can be useful instead of unix time tricks (but not sure :) ).